# Migration java 8 to 11. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish, apache-commons-fileupload

- I am migrating an application from java8 to java11, the changes I have made are :

1. I updated the maven compiler.version from 3.3 to 3.8.0
2. I updated the maven compiler.source from 1.8 to 11
3. I updated the maven compiler.target from 1.8 to 11
4. I replaced the javax dependencies with the corresponding jakarta ones, I followed the instructions in this [post](http://%20https://tuxtor.shekalug.org/consideraciones-generales-al-actualizar-proyectos-java-empresariales-desde-java-8-hacia-java-11/).

- I am using Eclipse and Glassfish 6.1.0, in glassfish I have to add some libraries that are important for the project, but I have had problems adding the commons-fileupload one, I found that the Apache Commons code that uses the javax package. * package does not compile with Jakarta EE 9 and GlassFish 6.1.0 code and the commons-fileupload depends on javax.servlet and the GlassFish admin console uses it to load implementations.
- Also, I'm working with:

  - JDK 11
  - GWT Eclipse Plugin 2.8.1
  - Eclipse 2021-03 (4.19.0) Build id: 20210312-0638
  - Glassfish 6.1.0

When I try to deploy the application I get this error:

```
[2021-12-07T14:34:55.416-0500] [glassfish 6.1] [SEVERE] [AS-WEB-CORE-00108] [jakarta.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=47 _ThreadName=admin-listener(3)] [timeMillis: 1638905695416] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5537)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
... 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addListener(StandardContext.java:2867)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addApplicationListener(StandardContext.java:2073)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureApplicationListener(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:212)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.TomcatDeploymentConfig.configureWebModule(TomcatDeploymentConfig.java:71)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModuleContextConfig.start(WebModuleContextConfig.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5534)
    ... 73 more
```

---

I attached both full [pom.xml](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15ihZ3NobILxrdJg1ApDY2aCNfkV_1uTr/view?usp=sharing) and server¨[log](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HQef2Xe-AVUuoN3PILhGthVdx0sHFYc3/view?usp=sharing) files.

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.focussscm</groupId>
    <artifactId>focussSCMParent</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>


    <modules>
        <module>../focussSCMModel</module>
        <module>../focussSCMJobsWSClientJobService</module>
        <module>../focussWSClientDataExchangeService</module>
        <module>../focussSCMBusiness</module>
        <module>../focussSCMJobs</module>
        <module>../focussSCMSecurity</module>
        <module>../focussSCM</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <!-- Explictly specify a default encoding to avoid relying on the OS locale. -->
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.build.scriptEncoding>Cp1252</project.build.scriptEncoding>

        <!-- Artifact versions -->
        <axis.version>1.4</axis.version>
        <commons-fileupload.version>1.4</commons-fileupload.version>
        <commons.discovery.version>0.2</commons.discovery.version>
        <gwt.version>2.9.0</gwt.version>
        <gwt-highcharts.version>1.7.0</gwt-highcharts.version>
        <gwtext.version>2.0.5</gwtext.version>
        <itext.version>5.4.2</itext.version>
        <jackson.version>1.8.10</jackson.version>
        <jakarta-faces.version>3.0.2</jakarta-faces.version>
        <jakarta.ws.rs.version>3.0.0</jakarta.ws.rs.version>
        <jakarta.xml.ws.version>4.0.0-RC1</jakarta.xml.ws.version>
        <jakarta.mail.version>2.0.1</jakarta.mail.version>
        <jakarta.ejb.version>4.0.0</jakarta.ejb.version>
        <jakarta.activation-api.version>2.0.1</jakarta.activation-api.version>
        <javax.wsdl.version>1.5.1</javax.wsdl.version>
        <jakarta.jws-api.version>3.0.0</jakarta.jws-api.version>
        <jakartarpc-api.version>1.1.4</jakartarpc-api.version>
        <jms.version>1.1</jms.version>
        <jmxri.version>1.2.1</jmxri.version>
        <jmxtools.version>1.2.1</jmxtools.version>
        <json.version>20171018</json.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <poi.version>3.9</poi.version>
        <org.quartz-scheduler.version>1.5.2</org.quartz-scheduler.version>
        <servlet-api.version>5.0.0</servlet-api.version>
        <smartgwt.version>4.0-focuss</smartgwt.version>
        
        <spring.version>5.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>5.3.4.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <slf4j-log4j.version>1.8.0-beta4</slf4j-log4j.version>
        
        <spring-security-web.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring-security-web.version>
        <spring-webmvc.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring-webmvc.version>
        <gwt.directory>pages/module/gwt</gwt.directory>

        <!-- Glassfish server variables -->  
`<glassfish.glassfishDirectory>C:\Development\Apps\Glassfish6</glassfish.glassfishDirectory>`
        <glassfish.user>User</glassfish.user>
        <glassfish.adminPassword>123456</glassfish.adminPassword>
        <glassfish.domain.name>fscmFocuss</glassfish.domain.name>
        <glassfish.domain.host>localhost</glassfish.domain.host>
        <glassfish.domain.adminPort>1234</glassfish.domain.adminPort>


        <!-- Maven GWT compiler version and parameters -->
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.resources.version>3.2.0</maven.resources.version>
        <compiler.style>OBF</compiler.style>
        <compiler.log.level>INFO</compiler.log.level>
        <glassfish.port>8081</glassfish.port>
        <install.plugin.version>2.5.2</install.plugin.version>

        <!-- Maven War plugin version and parameters -->
        <war.plugin.version>3.0.0</war.plugin.version>

        <!-- Maven ear plugin version and parameters -->
        <ear.plugin.version>2.10.1</ear.plugin.version>

        <cargo.maven3.plugin.version>1.9.3</cargo.maven3.plugin.version>
        
        <!-- ${basedir}/local.properties -->
        <dropbox.home>${dropbox.home.dir}</dropbox.home>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- package\GWT\gwt-servlet.jar -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-servlet -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-servlet</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- only_for_building\gwt\gwt-2.5.1\gwt-user.jar -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-user -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-user</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.gwtext/gwtext -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.gwtext</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwtext</artifactId>
                <version>${gwtext.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt-dev</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.gwt/gwt-dev -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>gwt</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
                        
            <!-- only_for_building\gwt\smartgwtpro-4.0\lib -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.isomorphic.smartgwt.pro</groupId>
                <artifactId>smartgwt-pro</artifactId>
                <version>${smartgwt.version}</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <!-- Exclusion: required to avoid conflicting with the asm dependency below -->
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>

            <!-- only_for_building\gwt\HighCharts\org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts-1.5.0.jar -->
            <!-- https://highcharts4gwt.github.io/ -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.moxieapps.gwt</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.moxieapps.gwt.highcharts</artifactId>
                <version>${gwt-highcharts.version}</version>
            </dependency>           

            <!-- only_for_building\axis\axis.jar -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis/axis -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
                <version>${axis.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- only_for_building\itextpdf-5.4.2 -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.itextpdf/itextpdf -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
                <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
                <version>${itext.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- only_for_building\log4j\log4j-1.2.15.jar -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/log4j/log4j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>${log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core -->
            <!-- <dependency> -->
            <!-- <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <version>${log4j.version}</version> -->
            <!-- </dependency> -->

            <!-- only_for_building\poi-3.9 -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
                <version>${poi.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>${poi.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- package\json -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-core-lgpl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.jackson/jackson-mapper-lgpl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
                <version>${jackson.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- only_for_building\json -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>${json.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.rpc/jakarta.xml.rpc-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.rpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.rpc-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakartarpc-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.servlet/jakarta.servlet-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.ws.rs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.ws.rs.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.ws/jakarta.xml.ws-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.xml.ws-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.xml.ws.version}</version>
            </dependency>       


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.mail/jakarta.mail-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.mail-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.mail.version}</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.ejb/jakarta.ejb-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.ejb</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.ejb-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.ejb.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.jws/jakarta.jws-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.jws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.jws-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.jws-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.activation/jakarta.activation-api -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta.activation-api.version}</version>
            </dependency>       


            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish/jakarta.faces -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
                <version>${jakarta-faces.version}</version>
            </dependency>                           
                        

            <!-- package\fileUpload\commons-fileupload-1.4.jar -->
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-fileupload/commons-fileupload -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>${commons-fileupload.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
            <!-- <dependency> -->
            <!-- <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>quartz</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <version>${org.quartz-scheduler.version}</version> -->
            <!-- </dependency> -->

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/opensymphony/quartz -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
                <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
                <version>${org.quartz-scheduler.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
            <!-- <dependency> -->
            <!-- <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId> -->
            <!-- <artifactId>quartz</artifactId> -->
            <!-- <version>${org.quartz-scheduler.version}</version> -->
            <!-- </dependency> -->
            
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-discovery/commons-discovery -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
                <version>${commons.discovery.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1/javax.wsdl -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.wsdl</artifactId>
                <version>${javax.wsdl.version}</version>
            </dependency>

            <!-- Security: Spring Core -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- Security: Spring Security -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
            </dependency>
                    
            <!-- Logging: Slf4j -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>${slf4j-log4j.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>${jstl.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- New -->
 
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.cargo/cargo-maven2-plugin -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${cargo.maven3.plugin.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>

        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>*/.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin to compile the project. Included here only to specifically 
                define the source and target versions of the project. Usage: mvn compile 
                (will compile java files to classes) -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>                 
                    <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>                   
                    <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>                   
                </configuration>            

            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.14.v20151106</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.6</version>
                </plugin> 
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${install.plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>
        
                <!-- Plugin to compile GWT Java code to JavaScript. Usage: mvn gwt:compile 
                    (will compile GWT files to JavaScript) -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${gwt.version}</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>compile</id>
                            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>compile</goal>
                                <goal>test</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>generateAsync</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Compiler parameters -->
                        <extraJvmArgs>-Xmx1024m -Xss1024k -Dgwt.nowarn.legacy.tools</extraJvmArgs>
                        <draftCompile>true</draftCompile>
                        <debugSuspend>false</debugSuspend>
                        <logLevel>${compiler.log.level}</logLevel>
                        <style>${compiler.style}</style>
                        <!-- Launch parameters with external server -->
                        <!-- Add the app to Glassfish embedded server and set the server to 
                            publsh automatically after each compile -->
                        <noServer>true</noServer>
                        <!-- Build parameters -->
                        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/${gwt.directory}</webappDirectory>
                        <deploy>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/${gwt.directory}</deploy>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${war.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

            
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cargo-maven3-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <container>
                            <containerId>glassfish4x</containerId>
                            <type>installed</type>
                            <!-- Path to directory where glassfish is installed -->
                            <home>${glassfish.glassfishDirectory}</home>
                        </container>
                        <configuration>
                            <type>existing</type>
                            <!-- Path to domains directory -->
                            <home>${glassfish.glassfishDirectory}/glassfish/domains</home>
                            <properties>
                                <!-- Domain name where application will be deployed. -->
                                <cargo.glassfish.domain.name>${glassfish.domain.name}</cargo.glassfish.domain.name>
                                <!-- Glassfish host -->
                                <cargo.hostname>${glassfish.domain.host}</cargo.hostname>
                                <!-- Glassfish admin port -->
                                <cargo.glassfish.admin.port>${glassfish.domain.adminPort}</cargo.glassfish.admin.port>
                                <!-- Glassfish user to authenticate -->
                                <cargo.remote.username>admin</cargo.remote.username>
                                <!-- Glassfish password to authenticate -->
                                <cargo.remote.password>${glassfish.adminPassword}</cargo.remote.password>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[2.8.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>compile</goal>
                                            <goal>site</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                  
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: This is most likely not related to your concrete `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener` error, but which GlassFish version are you using exactly? As far as I know GlassFish 6.0.0 still does not support JDK11. GlassFish 6.1 is the first to support h JDK11 https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/releases/6.1.0

Comment: Yes, I'm using Glassfish 6.1

Comment: GlassFish 6.x is Jakarta EE 9.x, which uses the `jakarta.*` package namespace. To be able to use your code with GlassFish 6.1 (and thus JakartaEE 9), you will need to change the packages imported by your code. If you want to continue to use the `javax.*` package namespace, you need to downgrade to a Jakarta EE 8 version, which is GlassFish 5.1.

Comment: It looks like commons-fileupload doesn't support JakartaEE ... yet.

Answer (score 2):

Your problems stem from the incompatibility between the Java EE 8 or earlier versus Jakarta EE 9 or later.

It looks the most recent official release of Apache Commons FileUpload still depends on the Java EE APIs.  However, looking at the commit history on GitHub, this commit:

- https://github.com/apache/commons-fileupload/commit/18db2b7e5a471b5bd81dab119db43c9efceda3cf

purports to remove Java EE and Jakarta EE dependencies from the Java code.   So, if were to check out the source  at that commit or later, you should be able to build a version of `commons-fileupload` that will run on either Java EE or Jakarta EE.

(Note: I haven't tried this out.)

Reading between the lines, I expect that will be a new official release of this library fairly soon.  Apparently, the Java EE dependency in `commons-fileupload` is a blocker for some other Apache Foundation projects.

---

The other alternative would be to keep your application at Java EE 8 (or earlier) for now, and use GlassFish 5.1 or earlier ... which requires Java 8 rather than Java 11.